# Example of difference b/w Abstract class & Interfaces with default method in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I know that there is already a question related to this, [Interface with default methods vs Abstract class in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998454/interface-with-default-methods-vs-abstract-class-in-java-8) but that question was asked way before Java 8 was released and it is just a gist of what is the difference between Abstract classes and interfaces with default methods, and it doesn't provide any practical examples at all, rather it is just full of wordily explanation.

I am posting this question because I am more interested in a practical example that clears the difference between an Abstract Class and Interface with a default method in Java 8.

Have a look at this example,

**Abstract Class,**

```
abstract class AbstractClass {

    public int var = 0;

    // These methods must be Overridden
    abstract int x();
    abstract int y();

    // This method is optional
    int z() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

**Interface (Java 8)**

```
interface Interface {

    public int var = 0;

    // These methods must be Overridden
    int x();
    int y();

    // This method is optional
    default int z(){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

How could I differentiate in above two if I want to explain its practical difference to a newbie Java programmer (like myself) ?

[this](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-default-methods/) article says,

> The benefit that default methods bring is that now it’s possible to
>   add a new default method to the interface and it doesn’t break the
>   implementations.

This couldn't possibly be the only benefit of interfaces with default methods, or is it ?

Comment: down voter, please explain the reason of down voting ? please don't just down vote and leave; I am here to learn and the only way i could avoid asking unclear questions if you will explain the reason of your down vote.

Comment: I didn't downvote the question, but note that explaining downvotes is explicitly discouraged by the SE management. Take a downvote to mean what it says on the button: *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"* (or that the person downvoting did so for a reason they probably shouldn't, which happens too).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you mean that a user shouldn't explain why he down voted a question ?

Comment: This feature virtually mimics Scala traits!!!!

Comment: That is *why* they have been introduced. Other differences: you may not make a default method final, and a default method may not access fields, since an interface doesn't have any.

Comment: It's a very slippery subject; see meta for the full back-and-forth on it. Posting a comment with suggestions for improving a post is always a good idea. Saying "-1 [some kind of explanation here]" is discouraged because, I'm told, it generates lots of back-and-forth without real value. Note this is not *my* policy. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should understand the difference between

```
abstract class AbstractClass {

    public int var = 0;

…
```

and

```
interface Interface {

    public int var = 0;

    …
```

The latter [is equivalent to](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3)

```
   public static final int var = 0;
```

which is entirely different to writing

```
   public int var = 0;
```

in an `abstract` class. This difference is already explained in the question you have linked by saying [“Abstract classes can have state”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19998768/2711488). Interfaces can only define constants. This implies that you can’t provide `default` methods for an `interface` performing any action with instance fields as an `interface` can’t define instance fields. `default` methods can only work atop other `interface` methods.

Sometimes it really helps trying to understand the “wordily explanation” rather than asking for “a practical example”. In other words, the question and answers you have linked are still valid.

Regarding the purpose of `default` methods in Java 8, that question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19998309/2711488) as well.

To summarize some differences between `abstract` classes and `interface`s:

- `interface` members are all `public`, you can’t define `private`, `protected` or package-private members; when you omit the `public` modifier it’s implied (starting with Java 9, `private` methods are allowed)
- `interface` fields are only for defining constants; they are implicitly `static final`
- `abstract` classes can have `static` class initializer code and instance constructors
- `abstract` classes may have state, i.e. define instance fields and provide methods working with them
- `abstract` classes can provide implementations for the methods `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` defined in `java.lang.Object` while `default` methods specified in `interface`s can’t override these methods
- `abstract` classes can define `final`, `strictfp`, `synchronized`, or `native` methods
- a `class` can extend only one `abstract` or concrete `class` but implement more than one `interface`