# why Interface Default methods?

Tags: java, java-8, default-method

Learning java 8 default methods . 
This [link](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/01/java-8-default-methods-explained-5-minutes/)  like any other resource on internet says

> In ‘the strictest sense’, Default methods are a step backwards because
>   they allow you to ‘pollute’ your interfaces with code. But they
>   provide the most elegant and practical way to allow backwards
>   compatibility. It made it much easier for Oracle to update all the
>   Collections classes and for you to retrofit your existing code for
>   Lambda.

My understanding is that java 8 dev/designers provided the default method in interfaces so that all implementing class does not have to unnecessarily
override same behavior, hence provide backward compatibility. For example :- if ForEach method would not have been default method, every collection implementing class had to implement it. Agreed .

To overcome that we could have had one class providing implementation of these default methods and then implementing class like arraylist etc could
have extended that. This way we could have statisfy both java fundamentals i.e reusability and abstraction i.e keeping the interface pollution less

I am sure java 8 dev/designer have already thought about this as they are much more learned and i am missing something here. Can someone help here so that we developers can also be on top of it as this major change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Purpose of Default or Defender methods in Java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998309/purpose-of-default-or-defender-methods-in-java-8)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> To overcome that we could have had one class providing implementation of these default methods and then implementing class like arraylist etc could have extended that.

Your suggestion would work only for standard JDK classes (since they usually extends some base classes such as `AbstractCollection` and `AbstractList`, were the implementation of the new methods can be added).

What about custom classes that implement JDK interfaces? If, for example, you have a class that implements `List` but doesn't extend some JDK `List` implementation, you should be able to switch to Java 8 without having to implement new methods in your class.

With `default` implementations of new methods in the `List` interface, you don't have to touch your custom class. You can later add a custom implementation to those methods if you are not satisfied by the default implementation.

Comment: In that case that custom class could also extend generic class implementing forEach implementation.But yes again limitation comes if that class already extending some class, my suggestion wont work.

Comment: `With default implementations of new methods in the List interface, you don't have to touch your custom class. You can later add a custom implementation to those methods if you are not satisfied by the default implementation.` Agreed. But also we are moving one step backward in some sense as we are diluting abstraction here  in some way

Comment: @MSach Even if it didn't extend some class, you would be forced to change its implementation (even if just to add an `extends someClass` clause).

Comment: Agreed with your last comment

Answer (score 17):

Before Java 8, `interfaces` could have only `abstract methods`. The implementation of these methods has to be provided in a separate class. So, if a new method is to be added in an `interface` then its implementation code has to be provided in the class implementing the same interface.

To overcome this issue, Java 8 has introduced the concept of `default methods` which allow the interfaces to have methods with implementation without affecting the classes that implement the `interface`.

The `default methods` were introduced to provide backward comparability so that existing `interfaces` can use the lambda expressions without implementing the methods in the implementation class. `Default methods` are also known as `defender methods` or `virtual extension methods`.

Comment: exactly - "for backward compatibility" . As far as we know, one of the developers said that this is exactly what default methods were invented for. But this does not mean that they should be used everywhere in the user code.

Comment: I don't know about using them "everywhere" but this form of backwards compatibility could be useful for more than just JDK devs. I don't see a big problem with it as long as you don't go too wild. Apparently they chose to make the feature accessible (and even advertise it) to developers.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a requirement to add new method to an interface, clients which use existing interface will be broken as classes needs to implement all methods in the interface.

In this scenario, [default and static methods](http://www.zoftino.com/java-interfaces) can be used. These methods can have body and clients don't need to implement them, so existing implementations work without any changes.

For example, if you want to enhance interfaces to add methods which accept lambda expressions, you can use default methods.